# Enabling HTTPS on Domain

Tags: ssl, https, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I have a vps running on ubuntu 12.04 with apache2. My question is, if I am going to install ssl cert and etc. to it am i able to use `https` directly to my domain? I just add `A Record` at my domain provider with the VPS IP Address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, yes.

Remember to make sure that Apache is listening on https (and it's setup as it should be with the certs and mod_ssl) and if you have a firewall active, the port for https (443) is open.

Otherwise, all you would need to do is add your record to the DNS server.

Comment: How about using cloudflare, am i able to use https? with the same config above.

Comment: From what I can tell on their site, only if you are hosting on Pro or better.  The free plan will not use SSL.

Comment: Two years later... I'm following up on this in case others have the same question.  Yes, CloudFlare's free plan will proxy https to your site, and it will even be a 'green-lock' connection (verified as secure).